# View list of voicemails

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, voicemail

I have a first gen Moto G running Android 5.1 that I purchased from [Republic Wireless](https://republicwireless.com/) about two to three years ago.  Whenever I receive a voicemail I get a notification.  If I tap the notification I get taken to a visual list of voice mails that I have received with the title saying "History".  If I tap the back button I am taken to the home screen of the Phone app.

I am unable to figure out **how to reach this list** of voicemails without having a notification for a new voicemail.

---

**Description of the Phone App**

On the home screen of the phone app I have the following tabs: Speed Dial, Recents, and Contacts.  Going through these three I have been unable to get to the list of voice mails.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the details for this question I figured it out.

There is a horizontal ellipse at the top-right of the screen.  Tapping that and then Call History brings up a screen with three tabs: All, Missed, and Voicemail.  The voicemail tab is what I was looking for.